# Ruby Pony alternative for Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, email, gmail

Pony is broken in ruby 1.9. Does any recommend any alternatives for me so I can send mail through my Gmail account? Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Pony works for me in Ruby 1.9, and I'm also using the gmail SMTP server. Here's how I have it set up...

```
require 'pony'
Pony.mail(:to => 'real_mail@yahoo.com', :via => :smtp, :via_options => {
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => '587',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name => 'id_gmail',
    :password => 'parola_gmail',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :domain => "HELO",
},
:subject => 'Test email', :body => 'Test for Pony email through gmail SMTP server.')
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [Mail](http://github.com/mikel/mail) from Mikel Lindsaar? It's got really great syntax

Comment: +1 for Mail. It's also the default email library for Rails as of Rails 3.

Comment: +1 for Mail. It's superbly written, the tests are terrific, and the documenation is thorough.